# my code does not terminate after downloading the last file

Tags: python

this is the code i am running, it does not end after downloading last file. i dont get the last print statment. plz help me here
the code has commments so that you can know what i am trying to do.
i give date as input, there is a url which is dynamic with date.
i do the url formating. it goes through all the dates i have given. and downloads the file in the given folder.
then at the end it should print how many file are downloaded. and it should end there. but code does not move ahead after downloading the last file. and so it does not terminate.

thank you.
plz let me know if you need more info.

```
import requests
import datetime
import os

def fno_eod_data(start_date, end_date, save_directory):
    url_base = 'https://archives.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2023/JUN/fo{}bhav.csv.zip'

    # Convert start date and end date to datetime objects
    start_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
    end_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, '%d-%m-%Y')

    # List of holidays to skip
    holidays = [
        '26-01-2023', '07-03-2023', '30-03-2023', '04-04-2023', '07-04-2023', '14-04-2023', '01-05-2023',
        '28-06-2023', '15-08-2023', '19-09-2023', '02-10-2023', '24-10-2023', '14-11-2023', '27-11-2023',
        '25-12-2023'
    ]

    # Iterate over the dates and download the files
    current_datetime = start_datetime
    files_downloaded = 0

    while current_datetime <= end_datetime:
        # Check if the current date is a weekend (Saturday or Sunday)
        if current_datetime.weekday() >= 5:
            current_datetime += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            continue

        # Format the current date as ddmmYYYY
        current_date = current_datetime.strftime('%d%b%Y').upper()

        # Check if the current date is a holiday
        if current_date in holidays:
            current_datetime += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            continue

        # Generate the URL for the specific date
        url = url_base.format(current_date)

        try:
            # Download the file
            response = requests.get(url)

            # Generate the filename with the current date
            filename = f'{current_date}.csv.zip'

            # Create the folder if it doesn't exist
            os.makedirs(save_directory, exist_ok=True)

            file_path = os.path.join(save_directory, filename)

            with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(response.content)

            files_downloaded += 1
            print(f'The file "{filename}" has been downloaded and saved to "{save_directory}".')

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f'Error downloading the file for the date "{current_date}": {e}')

        # Move to the next date
        current_datetime += datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    print(f'\nTotal files downloaded: {files_downloaded}')


# Code Run
start_date = '07-06-2023'
end_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
save_directory = r'*********************************'

fno_eod_data(start_date, end_date, save_directory)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Debugging your code, the request when the `current_datetime` is today's date, times out (added a timeout of 10s), probably because the file is not available yet.

```
Error downloading the file for the date "14JUN2023": HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.nseindia.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
```

You can either add a timeout to your request:

```py
            response = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
```

or update the `while` condition to:

```py
    while current_datetime < end_datetime:
```

Comment: let me try a timeout. that makes more sence why this dint come to my mind. haha. thank you will update if that works.